# labeling data in SVM opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to implement SVM in opencv for features that I have extracted features by using SIFT. I have extracted features for 2 different objects (each object has features of 10 different images which in total I got more than 3000 features for one object) and I put those features in one file (yaml file)..

My problem is: I don't know how to label them? so I need to label these two files (as I said each file is the type of yaml and it contains matrix 3260*128 and the second yaml file for the second object is 3349*128)...

So please help me to show me how to label these files in order to train them later on... I'm using openCV c++.. by the way, the openCV code for SVM is based on LIBSVM

Thank you in advanced

Comment: try letter-recog.cpp sample that come with opencv samples

Comment: in the letter-recog.cpp, the data is already labeled and all of them in the same file, in my case; I have 2 files, each file for a certain object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you get your matrix correctly, and each row represents one sample, what you can do is similar to what lakesh suggested:

```
Cv::Mat anger, disgust;
// Load the data into anger and disgust
...
// Make sure anger.cols == disgust.cols 
// Combine your features from different classes into one big matrix
int numPostives = anger.rows, numNegatives = disgust.rows;
int numSamples = numPostives+numNegatives;
int featureSize = anger.cols;
cv::Mat data(numSamples, featureSize, CV_32FC1) // Assume your anger matrix is in float type
cv::Mat positiveData = data.rowRange(0, numPostives);
cv::Mat negativeData = data.rowRange(numPostives, numSamples);
anger.copyTo(positiveData);
disgust.copyTo(negativeData);
// Create label matrix according to the big feature matrix
cv::Mat labels(numSamples, 1, CV_32SC1);
labels.rowRange(0, numPositives).setTo(cv::Scalar_<int>(1));
labels.rowRange(numPositives, numSamples).setTo(cv::Scalar_<int>(-1));
// Finally, train your model
cv::SVM model;
model.train(data, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), cv::SVMParams());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Labeling is easy. Just label one of the classes/objects as 1 and the other as -1.

```
                  case 'Anger'
                     CVTrainLabel = [CVTrainLabel;1];
                     Hist = UniformLBP2(I1);
                     CVTrainVec = [CVTrainVec;Hist];
                     continue;
                 case 'Disgust'
                    CVTrainLabel = [CVTrainLabel;-1];
                     Hist = UniformLBP2(I1);
                     CVTrainVec = [CVTrainVec;Hist];
```

Comment: do you have any sample of code.. don't forget i have here 2 files and each file contains features for a certain object

Comment: Hey lakesh, i didn't get your point here :(.... let's say, i have a file which is Anger.yaml (which contains features for the first object) and the second file which is Disgust.yaml (contains the second object features) so how to do it in this case? I have load it by using the function filestorage and i can read the matrices inside these files correctly...

Comment: this is my suggestion: Write a separate code where u load the features and at the same time, assign labels as the example. when u load anger file, add 1 to the existing label  and when disgust, add -1 to the existing label...

Comment: I think your code is a python, because I don't see it's close to c++.. or I beg you to give more details about it, because I'm really confused about it